# Implement a regular interface in a spring data repository interface

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using a Repository that extends a spring data JpaRepository and would like to let it extend another interface.

Previously, my db repository looked like this:

```kotlin
interface PublicTransportPricingZoneRepository : JpaRepository<PublicTransportPricingZone, Long> {

}
```

I have now created another interface `TransitTicketRepo` as defined below

```kotlin
interface TransitTicketRepo {
    fun findPossibleTickets(geometry: Geometry): Collection<TransitTicket>
}
```

and now would like to implement the interface with a default method in `PublicTransportPricingZoneRepository`. I've tried to solve this by changing the code of my PublicTransportPricingZoneRepository to

```kotlin
interface PublicTransportPricingZoneRepository : JpaRepository<PublicTransportPricingZone, Long>, TransitTicketRepo {
    fun findPossibleTickets(geometry: Geometry): Collection<TransitTicket> {
       // do something
       return emptyList()
    } 
}
```

but get the following error message when starting the application.

`org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Collection PublicTransportPricingZoneRepository.findPossibleTickets(Geometry); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Collection...`

I'm assuming the solution is to somehow tell spring data to stop auto-generating a query for `findPossibleTickets` but have been unable to find out how.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it [this way](https://vladmihalcea.com/custom-spring-data-repository/)

In short.:

```
@Repository
// Your bean that will be glued together by spring
interface PublicTransportPricingZoneRepository extends JpaRepository<...>, PublicTransportPricingZoneCustomRepository {
  // Other methods, but everything must be annotated with @Query or possible for spring to guess what it needs to do from its name (google derived methods)
}

interface PublicTransportPricingZoneCustomRepository {
  // define custom methods
  List<String> nameIsNotImportant();
}

@Service
// naming here is important - it must be names as interface + Impl, otherwise spring won't pick it up
// apart from that, it's a regular bean - you can Autowire, etc
class PublicTransportPricingZoneCustomRepositoryImpl implementats PublicTransportPricingZoneCustomRepository {
  // Implement custom methods
  @Overridden
  public List<String> nameIsNotImportant() {
    // impl
  }
}
```

Comment: That does not work for me - Spring still tries to auto-generate an implementation for `nameIsNotImportant()` which leads to the mentioned error.